# How can I avoid changing a single CheckBox entry in a TableView. All other CheckBox Entries should be changable

Tags: javafx-8

How can I avoid changing a single CheckBox entry in a TableView.
All other CheckBox Entries should be changable.
It should not possible do deselect a specific Entry.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_1

```
    package checkbox;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.Callback;

    public class TableCellFactorySample extends Application {
        public static final String DONT_MISS = "Love";

        private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
            Group root = new Group();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            final ObservableList<Needs> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Needs(true, "Gold"),
                    new Needs(false, "SUV"), new Needs(true, DONT_MISS), new Needs(true, "Diamonds"),
                    new Needs(false, "Boot"));

            TableColumn<Needs, Boolean> neededColumn = new TableColumn<>("Need Things");
            neededColumn.setMinWidth(50);
            neededColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                    new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Needs, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

                        @Override
                        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<Needs, Boolean> param) {
                            Needs need = param.getValue();
                            SimpleBooleanProperty needBooleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(need.isNeeded());
                            needBooleanProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                                @Override
                                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue,
                                        Boolean newValue) {
                                    if (need.getName().equals(DONT_MISS)) {
                                        System.err.println("Avoid changing the Checkbox");
                                    } else {
                                        System.err.println("Changing");
                                    }
                                    System.err.println(need.getName() + " / " + needBooleanProperty + "\n");
                                }
                            });
                            return needBooleanProperty;
                        }
                    });

            neededColumn.setCellFactory(//
                    new Callback<TableColumn<Needs, Boolean>, TableCell<Needs, Boolean>>() {
                        @Override
                        public TableCell<Needs, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Needs, Boolean> abbreviation) {
                            CheckBoxTableCell<Needs, Boolean> checkBoxTableCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<Needs, Boolean>();
                            checkBoxTableCell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                            return checkBoxTableCell;
                        }
                    });

            TableColumn<Needs, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
            nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Needs, String>("name"));

            TableView<Needs> tableView = new TableView<>();
            tableView.setItems(data);
            tableView.setEditable(true);
            tableView.getColumns().add(neededColumn);
            tableView.getColumns().add(nameColumn);
            root.getChildren().add(tableView);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            init(primaryStage);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }


    package checkbox;

    public class Needs {
        private boolean needed;
        private String name;

        Needs(boolean needed, String name) {
            this.needed = needed;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isNeeded() {
            return needed;
        }

        public void setNeeded(boolean needed) {
            this.needed = needed;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired result with multiple solutions. Two of them are as below:

**Solution#1:** Reset the value if you dont want to change

```
neededColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Needs, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<Needs, Boolean> param) {
                Needs need = param.getValue();
                SimpleBooleanProperty needBooleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(need.isNeeded());
                ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                        if (need.getName().equals(DONT_MISS)) {
                            System.err.println("Avoid changing the Checkbox");
                            // RESET THE VALUE WHEN YOU DONT WANT TO CHANGE
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                needBooleanProperty.removeListener(this);
                                needBooleanProperty.set(oldValue);
                                needBooleanProperty.addListener(this);
                            });
                        } else {
                            System.err.println("Changing");
                        }
                        System.err.println(need.getName() + " / " + needBooleanProperty + "\n");
                    }
                };
                needBooleanProperty.addListener(listener);
                return needBooleanProperty;
            }
        });
```

**Solution#2:** Dont allow to interact with checkbox if you dont want to change

```
neededColumn.setCellFactory(//
                new Callback<TableColumn<Needs, Boolean>, TableCell<Needs, Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<Needs, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Needs, Boolean> abbreviation) {
                        CheckBoxTableCell<Needs, Boolean> checkBoxTableCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<Needs, Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                setDisable(false);
                                if (getTableRow() != null && !empty) {
                                    Needs needs = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                                    if (needs.getName().equals(DONT_MISS)) {
                                        setDisable(true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        checkBoxTableCell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        return checkBoxTableCell;
                    }
                });
```